# Uncheck checkbox present in header ng-grid

Tags: ng-grid

I'm using ng-grid in which checkboxes are enabled.

```
showSelectionCheckbox: true
```

Below is plunker created for the same

http://plnkr.co/edit/rtkDYvDygRn38VU9Cmsk?p=preview

In this plunker, click on select all checkbox present in header.
Then click on the button below which will refresh the table content.
After clicking on the button, you can see that data got refreshed, but select all checkbox present in header is still selected.
How to uncheck that checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this. It worked for me.

```
var allChecked = $("input.ngSelectionHeader:checkbox").prop('checked');
if (allChecked) {
$("input.ngSelectionHeader:checkbox").click();
}
else {
$scope.gridOptions.selectAll(false);
}
```